# Why is scanf failing to read inputs correctly?

Tags: c

I cant figure out whats wrong. Am i using format specifiers in wrong way? Someone please help i am very new to coding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name[20];int age;char grade;double gpa;char area[10];
    printf("User Input\n");
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name,20,stdin);
    printf("Your name is %s\n",name);
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d\n",&age);
    printf("Your age is %d\n",age);
    printf("Enter you grade: ");
    scanf("%c\n",&grade);
    printf("Your grade is %c\n",grade);//Why is this giving an int output?
    printf("Enter your gpa: ");
    scanf("%f\n",&gpa);
    printf("Your gpa is %f\n",gpa);
    printf("Enter your area: ");
    scanf("%s\n",&area);
    printf("Your area is %s",area);//This shows grade input
    return 0;
}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Remove the `\n` from your `scanf` format specifiers. And also `"%c"` -> `" %c"`. Warning: `scanf` is pretty difficult to use.

Comment: For doubles use `%lf` in `scanf`. For `printf` you don't have to.

Comment: Why you don't want those newlines in your scanf format strings: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html

Comment: C is *not* the best language for learning basic programming - some aspects of the language are *deeply* unintuitive and inconsistent, and it assumes you know what you're doing at all times.  I compare it to using an old table saw with no blade guards and frayed wiring.  Yes, it's an important language to learn (it's the substrate upon which most of our modern computing ecosystem is built), but it *sucks* as a teaching language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `fgets` correctly when reading `name`. I'd recommend also using `fgets` for all your other inputs, and then parsing the intended values out of them.  For example:

```
char age_str[20];
fgets(age_str, 20, stdin);
age = strtol(age_str, NULL, 10);
```

This is preferable to using `scanf` directly for non-string inputs since if input fails to match a format string, it will remain in `stdin` and screw up the other `scanf` calls.

If you would like to use `scanf` correctly:

- Check its return value to see if it matches the number of format specifiers in the string. If not, some inputs were not successfully read. You may want to use a `do`/`while` loop for this.
- Begin your format strings with a space, as in `" %c"`, so that any whitespace remaining in `stdin` will be skipped over.
- [Don't end your format strings with a newline](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some things to remember about `scanf`:

- Most conversion specifiers like `%s`, `%d`, and `%f` will skip over leading whitespace - `%c` and `%[` will not.  If you want to read the next single non-whitespace character, use `" %c"` - the leading blank tells `scanf` skip over any leading whitespace before reading the next non-whitespace character;
- For what you are trying to do, you should not use `\n` in your format strings - it will cause `scanf` to block until you enter a non-whitespace character;
- You do not need to use the `&` operator on array expressions like `area`; under most circumstances, array expressions are converted to pointer expressions<sup>1</sup>.  Honestly, you should read `area` the same way you read `name`, using `fgets` (and you should always check the result of `fgets`), or you should specify the maximum field width in the specifier: `scanf( "%9s", area );` (a 10-element array can hold up to a 9-character string, since one element has to be reserved for the string terminator);
- You should get in the habit of checking the result of `scanf` - it will return the number of successful conversions and assignments.  For example, `scanf( "%d %d", &x, &y )` will return 2 if both `x` and `y` are read successfully.  It will return `EOF` if end-of-file is signaled or there's a read error.
- `scanf` will read up to the next character that doesn't match the conversion specifier - IOW, if you're using `%d`, then `scanf` will skip over any leading whitespace, then read up to the next character that isn't a decimal digit.  That character is left in the input stream.  This means if you're using `%d` and type in `123e456`, `scanf` will read up to that `'e'` character and assign `123` to the target.  If you try to read again with `%d`, `scanf` will immediately stop reading on that `e` and return 0 without assigning anything to the target (this is called a matching failure).  This will continue until you remove that `'e'` from the input stream (such as with `getchar` or `fgetc` or `scanf` with the `%c` specifier, etc.
- You need to make sure the types of the arguments match the format specifier.  `%s` expects an argument of type `char *`, `%d` expects `int *`, `%f` expects `float *`. `%x` expects `unsigned int *`, `%lf` expects `double *`, etc.

---

1. This is one of the "deeply unintuitive" aspects of C I was talking about in my comment.